# ¿Cómo hacer que un ejecutable de C solo se ejecute desde la terminal?

Tags: c, cmd, exe

Estoy buscando una manera de que un ejecutable de C solo pueda ejecutarse desde la terminal. Que no se pueda ejecutar dando doble click encima.

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En rigor, no podés impedir que se ejecute porque es el sistema operativo el que se encarga de eso. Es decir que tu aplicación eventualmente se ejecutará y vos podrías tratar de detectar la situación y decidir continuar con la ejecución o no dependiendo del caso.
Asumo que estás pensando en Windows (ya que no especificaste el sistema operativo). Si ese es el caso podés intentar usando la llamada [GetStdHandle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle).

```
if (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    exit(-1);
}
```

La idea es pedirle el *handler* de salida estándar al sistema operativo. Las aplicaciones que no son específicamente de terminal no la tienen. Deberías asegurarte de que tu aplicación al compilarse no establezca este *handler* ya que si usás una entorno de desarrollo como el de Microsoft es probable que lo haga si usás un proyecto para desarrollar aplicaciones para terminal.

Esta solución no es 100% segura. Alguien podría configurar Windows para que le asigne un *handler* de salida a la aplicación. Y entonces no entraría en la condición.